Water dripping down basement walls during heavy rain from the south and from one window header
I would appreciate advice. I have had water dripping from the window header in my master bathroom during a heavy rain from the south. I also have noticed a trickle of water down my basement wall which is under the bathroom area (but not directly under it). This only happens on one side (the front) of the house. Fortunately this only happens a few times per year during the heavy wind driven rain. We have made several changes trying to alleviate the problem: brand new larger gutters, all exterior window caulk professionally replaced, new flashing professionally done around front porch. At this point we think the source could be the windows on the front of the house…the weep holes are clear but we suspect the bottom corners may not be sealed or have cracks so our next step is to try silicone caulk in all of those window corners. We have stone on the front of the house. We do not see any cracks. But is this something we should seal? We see no other signs of water in the rest of the house. We are also contemplating removing the wall around the window in the bathroom to check for water damage and/or mold. Two days ago we had 8 inches of rain in 5 hours and the leaks were significantly worse. The basement was dripping in new areas along the front wall of the foundation. For clarity, the water is coming from above and not through any cracks in the basement wall.


Have you checked in the attic for roof leaks/stains?  Water from roof leaks can travel some distance from the leak before dropping down/showing.
